# How do sign in to firestore from python

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I managed to create a user with email and password but I cannot find a way to check a user details in order to login. Looked on firebase docs but I couldn't find a function for login

```
from flask import jsonify, request
import app.firebase_utils
from firebase_admin import auth
from app import app

            
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signin():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.get_json()
        email = data.get('email')
        password = data.get('password')
        try:
            # find the user with the email
            find_user = auth.get_user_by_email(email)
            print(find_user)

            #CODE TO CHECK USER
            #if the user exists check password
            #check_password
            #if email+password ok then loging and send confirmation
            return jsonify('User logged in succesfully!')
        except Exception as e:
            return jsonify(str(e))
            
    else:
        return jsonify('method is get')
```

Comment: What are the details you are looking for?

Comment: i'm looking for a function similar to the one I used to create an user like below

`try:
            existing_user = auth.get_user_by_email(email)
            return jsonify('User already exists')
        except auth.UserNotFoundError:
            try:
                user = auth.create_user(
                    email=email,
                    password=password)
                return jsonify('Succesfully created new user!')
            except Exception as e:
                return jsonify(str(e))`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What similar function are you referring at?

Comment: so I can create a new user with `auth.create_user(email=email, password=password)` but I can't find one to login with email and password from python

Comment: I have answered earlier today the exact same question. Please check the duplicate to see why there is an absence of a login function.

Comment: right, I didn't find that question when I was searching. so I take it I need to add a login function on client side ( react in my case ) to handle login and then send data to the server ?